# How to get data from brackets in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have a table (that shape I can't control) where I have one column in data type varchar(500), but strings are in the brackets.

[image: my_table]

Can I get data from these brackets in another way than this?

```
select *
from my_table
where products LIKE '%c%'
;
```

I tried to change data type for array, json, jsonb - but it doesn't work.

"Products" are always in the same order, but not every user has all of them and some have nothing.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you need to show an example of the desired output.